# ¿como recorrer el siguiente arreglo? en php

Tags: php, array

```
 Array
 (
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [estatus] => ok
                [mensaje] => Mensaje enviado
                [referencia] => 2017081504081721546
                [numcelular] => 7711998999
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [estatus] => ok
                [mensaje] => Mensaje enviado
                [referencia] => 2017081504081737255
                [numcelular] => 7711279856
            )

    )

 )
```

Comment: Con dos For each, para ir recorriendo cada nivel

Comment: me podrias dar un ejemplo por favor no encuentro ninguno :-(

Comment: Aquí puedes encontrar un ejemplo https://joshtronic.com/2014/03/03/using-list-foreach/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí muestro una forma de leerlo. Tendrías que interactuar dentro de la primera clave del array, por como lo estás recibiendo.

#### `Código:` [`Ver Demo`](http://rextester.com/UVE12952)

```
<?php



$arr=array(
            array(
                    array(  "estatus" => "ok", 
                            "mensaje" => "Mensaje enviado",
                            "referencia" => 2017081504081721546,
                            "numcelular" => 7711998999),
                    array(  "estatus" => "ok", 
                            "mensaje" => "Mensaje enviado",
                            "referencia" => 2017081504081737255,
                            "numcelular" => 7711279856)
            )
    );

print_r($arr);


foreach ($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    foreach ($v as $k1=>$v1)
    {
        echo "DATOS $k1<br /><br />";
        echo $v1["estatus"]."<br />";
        echo $v1["mensaje"]."<br />";
        echo $v1["referencia"]."<br />";
        echo $v1["numcelular"]."<hr />";
    }

}
?>
```

---

#### `Resultado:`

Este es el array como lo tienes ahora:

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [estatus] => ok
                    [mensaje] => Mensaje enviado
                    [referencia] => 2017081504081721546
                    [numcelular] => 7711998999
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [estatus] => ok
                    [mensaje] => Mensaje enviado
                    [referencia] => 2017081504081737255
                    [numcelular] => 7711279856
                )

        )

)
```

Este es el resultado de la lectura:

```html
DATOS 0<br /><br />ok<br />Mensaje enviado<br />2017081504081721546<br />7711998999<hr />DATOS 1<br /><br />ok<br />Mensaje enviado<br />2017081504081737255<br />7711279856<hr />
```

Comment: Gracias ya quedo. Justo lo que buscaba